# Eclipse - Unable to connect repository

Tags: eclipse-plugin

The error showing up is:

```
Unable to read repository at "Can't connect to SOCKS proxy:SOCKS"
```

Even after adding these lines to `.ini` file I am getting the above error:

```
vmargs
Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
```

The ports are set to:

```
HTTP to  80
HTTPS to 443
SOCK to 1080
```

When I did this for the first time I could update mars. Once mars was updated I wanted to install the following https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/mars but I am getting the error. The main intention is to install modeling of HANA which I am not able to do.

Kindly anyone help me out with this issue as soon as possible.

Comment: Do you need SOCKS? There once was a problem with proxy and SOCKS. If you don't really need that, try highlighting the "SOCKS" line and use the "Clear" button to remove it. Then try again.

Comment: Hi Calon, I have already tried clearing SOCKS and also somewhere I found it has to be changed to some other port number too but that doesn't seem to work.